# How to write "First of every month in Ruby"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, iterator

I'm trying to write an iterator in ruby that sends a callback on the first of every month.

How would you write something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if Date.today.day == 1
  #do something
end
```

I'm not sure what you mean by an iterator - i hope you don't mean some program that keeps looping, constantly asking if today is the first day of the month?  Sounds like a waste of resources.  Use crontab :)

Comment: Cronjob! All obeisances to our fearless leader Cronos.

Answer (score 2):

```
if my_date.beginning_of_day == Time.now.beginning_of_month
  my callback
end
```

Comment: That would be Rails specific. But yes, I do see the `ruby-on-rails` tag.